# error when installing a wordpress theme on Ampps (Softaculous)

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, themes, ampps

I have installed the latest version of Ampps (Softaculous), the version is 3.6 (windows 7 professional 64bit). Everything fine here. I have installed also Wordpress, ok everything fine here. Then, I tried to install a wordpress theme but it didn't work, everytime I have this error (I tried several themes..):

> Blockquote
>   "Installazione fallita: Download non riuscito. cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

I guess I am missing some configuration but I don't know what.. can you help me?
Thanks

Edit:

this is part of my php ini file:

```
[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\cacert.pem"
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

Comment: Seems to me like it's a permission error. Try changing the permission settings.

Comment: thanks for the reply, where can I change the permission settings?

Comment: I have never used this app so I don't know, just a suggestion...

Comment: @dingo_d Softaculous is a good one. It manages all the permissions while installing a WordPress, i have used it. Permission is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can install a theme in 2 ways:
1. Download a theme. Place it in themes folder. Go to wp-admin panel and activate it.
2. Go to wp-admin panel, download a theme and install it from admin panel only.

I think you followed the second way. It seems While downloading a theme from admin panel, it is using cURL.

> curl used to include a list of accepted CAs, but no longer bundles ANY
>   CA certs. So by default it'll reject all SSL certificates as
>   unverifiable. You'll have to get your CA's cert and point curl at it.
>   More details at cURLS's Details on [Server SSL Certificates](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html).

The error is probably caused by not having an up-to-date bundle of CA root certificates.

You need to make sure that your installation of PHP has one of these files, and that it’s up to date (otherwise download one here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html). Then set in php.ini:

```
curl.cainfo = <absolute_path_to> cacert.pem
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried to do as you told me but nothing changed but maybe this time i did something wrong? following also another guide on internet i add also this two lines of code, so in my php.ini I have this:



[curl]
; A default value for the CURLOPT_CAINFO option. This is required to be an
; absolute path.
curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin\cacert.pem"
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

Comment: how can I fix this problem?

Comment: The above solutions should work. Try once again and still you are not able to solve - disable varification for host and pear:

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: sorry for the late reply, ok I try to add these two lines in php.ini:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: I tried but nothing changed.. help please help me, I really need to make it works for my job.. :(